# Sentence improvement

Tags: pronouns, syntactic-analysis

The given sentence is-

*'As no one knows the truth **as fully as him, no one but him can** provide the testimony.'*

As far as the highlighted part is concerned, I improved it as-

*'As no one knows the truth **as fully as he does, no one but he alone can** provide the testimony.'*

What's is wrong in the above sentence? I am struck.

Comment: Change the first word from _As_ to _Since_ and there's no problem. Three different uses of _as_, one a conjunction, and the others part of an equative construction. This poses problems since it's not obvious which _as_'s are relating to which other _as_'s. In speech, intonation could be used, but changing _as_ to _since_ gets rid of the confusion. _Since_ is far more common than _as_ in this construction, anyway.

Comment: @FumbleFingers There is but which can be a **["a preposition"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/but)** A bit different element from the link.

Comment: @Rathony: I don't see the relevance of ***but** used as preposition* to the ***as** [adjective] **as** [noun]* construction being queried by OP here. ***But*** I do see the relevance of the duplicate question I linked to.

Comment: @FumbleFingers What I meant was **but"" seems to have caused him a confusion here unlike your link. I am not saying it is completely different.

Comment: @Rathony: Per my comments to egrunin's post, this question is about accusative / nominative pronouns *(**him/he**)*, not ***but***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I know. But *but* was involved in changing *he* to *him* in **'As no one knows the truth as fully as him, no one but him can provide the testimony**. Without *no one but*, him should be changed to *he*. That's why i said *but* could have caused him a confusion there.

Comment: @Rathony It's a bit misleading to talk about *without **no-one but*** there, since the grammatical subject of the clause is ***no-one***. If you were going to remove an "optional component", it would be ***but him***. Of course, the accusative/nominative issue still comes into play, since [*no-one but **he** can*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22no-one+but+he+can%22) is at least as valid as the ***him*** version.

Comment: @FumbleFingers He is a foreigner and the sentences appeared in the exam. As no one knows the truth **as fully as him, no one but him** can provide the testimony needed to clear the accused of the very serious charges. (A)as fully as him, no one but him (B)as fully as he, no one but him (C)as fully as he, no one but he (D)as fully as he does, no one but he (E)as fully as he does, no one but he alone. The question is more confusing because of *but* rather than as X as Y where Y should start with **nominative**. Hope you understand my point now. I am not disagreeing with you.

Comment: @Rathony: As far as I'm concerned, the question is a duplicate anyway (I assume what OP is *really* interested in is the *as X as Y* construction). The *no-one but X* construction is a completely separate issue, which has no syntactic relevance to the usage under consideration.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, you are right. It is a completely separate issue. Pls read the explanation for the right choice. (b) is the correct answer. Explanation: **Choice (a) is wrong because the nominative form (*he*) is required: 'as fully as him' is wrong. Similarly, '*does*' is not required as given in other choices.** That's why I mentioned it has a bit different element there.

Comment: @Rathony: I hesitate to say *no-one knows as well as **I**,* but any concept of "correctness" here smacks of pedantry. Idiomatically though, what we *can* say is that the average native speaker today is far more likely to say *no-one knows as well as **me**.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers I can't agree with you more. This **seemingly** *hilarious* question appeared in the GMAT preparation book in India and other Asian countries. Wow! Isn't it shocking? I know how you feel now as I was as frustrated as you when I first saw this question.

Comment: Alright. I got the first part. Can you elaborate on the second part- 'no one but he alone can' ?

Comment: I already posted the answer and explanation in the above comment. This question is pretty bad for anyone who wants to learn English seriously. You will know what is wrong with the second part after reading my comment.

Answer (score -1):

- Omit needless words.
- Make the second clause a consequent of the
  first.
- Use parallel construction for reinforcement.

> No one else knows the truth as fully, so no one else can provide the testimony.

Comment: This is "peripheral writing advice", not an answer to the question as posed.

Comment: The subject is 'sentence improvement', the question is 'what is wrong?'. I gave an example of how it might be improved, and explained what I felt was wrong.

Comment: The question tags are *pronouns* and *sentence-structure* (I don't think *'sentence improvement'* would be accepted as an ELU tag). Essentially, OP is asking about the difference between *as X as **he** [is]* and *as X as **him***. Sidestepping the issue by rephrasing might be a useful comment, but it's not an *answer* in this context.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean.